# How do I access objects within an array of an API inside Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access [this](https://dictionaryapi.dev/) free dictionary API in Unity.

I'm getting this error: ***JSON must represent an object type.***

I think I know the cause of the error. It is probably because I'm trying to access an object inside the array directly.

How do I access an object within an array in API inside Unity?

Below is my code:

**APIHelper**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public static class APIHelper
{
    public static Words GetWord()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<Words>(json);
    }
}
```

**Words**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Words
{
    public string word;
}
```

**MainScript**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI wordText;

    public void WriteWord()
    { 
        Words w = APIHelper.GetWord();
        wordText.text = w.word;
    }
}
```

Comment: The JSON you get from the URL is an object, so when you parse it, you have to parse it to an array or a list as well.

Comment: Why did you delete [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74400817/lerp-forward-backward-by-x-values-when-a-key-is-pressed) question just now?  All you had to do was reset `moveRight` to `false` at the start of your method or elsewhere as applicable.